# Maximizing an AlertDialog?

Tags: android

I'd like to show a Dialog that occupies as much screen space as possible.

So, here's a sample:

```
AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx)......create();
Window w = dialog.getWindow();
WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = w.getAttributes();
lp.width = 320;
lp.height = 480;
w.setAttributes(lp);
```

Problem is, this doesn't change a thing. Why?

TIA.

Comment: I’d like to answer “because C# is more cleverer than you and won’t allow it because it’s a stupid thing to do” but I think the explanation is something a lot simpler. :/

Comment: See that tag that says "Android"? That means Java. Before you go insulting people you should figure out what you're talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to do exactly what you're wanting, but isn't this mostly defeating the purpose of a Dialog? Why not just create a custom Activity and use the Dialog theme if you're just wanting it to look dialog-ey.

Comment: Because of the overhead and the fact that this dialog is a part of an activity.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the window layout parameters AFTER setContentView. Anything you do to the window before then (size/location-wise) will be tossed out when you call setContentView.

http://devstream.stefanklumpp.com/2010/07/android-display-dialogs-in-fullscreen.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to add minWidth and minHeight attributes in the Dialog's xml layout file. E.g. your screen size is 800 * 480, then set `android:minWidth="800dip"`, `android:minHeight="400dip"`